# Wrong greek character encoding on Wordpress Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, character-encoding

I try to call a function with jQuery and Ajax in Wordpress and return HTML code to append in part of the website.

This is the code where I create the code

```
$text = '
        <tr>
            <td class="row-label">
                <div style="padding-top:0px;">' . $greek_text . '</div>
                <div class="stock-text">Stock</div>
                <div class="stock-test">Test</div>
            </td>
         </tr>';
$result['type'] = 'success';
$result['table'] = $text;
echo json_encode($result);
die();
```

`$greek_text` is a woocommerce attribute name where I get directly from the database.

And this is the jQuery part

```
jQuery.ajax({
          type : "post",
          dataType : "json",
          url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
          data : {action: "print__table", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
          success: function(response) {

             if(response.type == "success") {
                console.log(response.table);
             }
             else {
                console.log('something goes really wrong');
             }
          },
          error: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
          }
       });
```

The text from `$greek_test` is returned as `%ce%ba%cf%8c%ce%ba%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%bd%ce%bf` instead of `κόκκινο`

I tried:

- `sanitize_title`
- `mb_convert_encoding` to UTF-8 and ISO 8859-7
- `esc_attr`
- `esc_html`

The return of `admin-ajax.php` has a header of `content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

However, it is still not returned correctly

Comment: use `esc_attr($greek_text )` this should work

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. Still got the same text